# How can I apply all changes from Plastic to Git

Tags: plasticscm

I get the following error when I try to sync with Git:

> `The branch(es) /main, /development has more than one head. Please merge it to be able to continue synchronizing`

The `/main` and `/development` branches are merged (from `main` to `development`) in Plastic.

I want to apply all changes from Plastic to Git. Plastic originally has all data from Git.

We've been using only Plastic for the last 2 months and want to merge back to Git.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unify/merge the different heads of your Plastic branch before being able to sync it with it.
http://www.plasticscm.net/topic/2977-cant-sync-with-git-due-to-message-branch-has-more-than-one-head/

Comment: Thanks, I was able to continue after I reviewed all histories from branch view and merged additional heads.